# Decoding json in golang without declaring type relationship?

Tags: json, go

I don't want to specify the type of my json since they are so messy and so complicated, I just want them to load into memory and I perform the lookup when needed.

It is easy with dynamic language such as python, e.g.

```
data = json.loads(str)
if "foo" in data:
   ...
```

How to do the same in go?

Comment: the method described in the answer about unmarshalling into `interface{}` is indeed correct, but from experience, in complex json objects, it's a nightmare, and you are better off specifying the data structure in advance.

Comment: So, why exactly don't you want to specify the type? What do you mean by messy? Can't you simplify it?

Answer (score 1):

You can unmarshal into an `interface{}` value to decode arbitrary JSON.

Taking the example from http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go

```
b := []byte(`{"Name":"Wednesday","Age":6,"Parents":["Gomez","Morticia"]}`)
var f interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &f); err != nil {
    ... handle error
}
```

You need to use a type switch to access data decoded in this way. For example:

```
age := f.(map[string)interface{})["Age"].(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which seems easier to understand for me, I hope it works for you too:
https://gobyexample.com/json . Look for the word "arbitrary"